# How to stop or destroy VideoView in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my main Activity I am playing an Video on VideoView when user click on Skip button :-

```
 skip_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                vv.stopPlayback();
                vv = null;
                video_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                main_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
            }
        });
```

Next Activity will open till now this is working fine but when coming back to previous Activity having VideoView it is taking long time to back.

And this is Console Message Desplaying:

```
04-23 16:09:29.091: I/MediaPlayer(3152): MediaPlayer 

04-23 16:09:29.091: I/MediaPlayer(3152): MediaPlayer setDataSource(context, uri,headers)

04-23 16:09:29.201: I/MediaPlayer(3152): MediaPlayer setDisplay()

04-23 16:09:29.311: I/MediaPlayer(3152): MediaPlayer handleMessage what=5

04-23 16:09:29.311: I/MediaPlayer(3152): MediaPlayer handleMessage what=1

04-23 16:09:29.311: D/MediaPlayer(3152): getMetadata
```

Comment: i want to finish videoview at the time of skipbutton clicked because

Comment: because 04-23 16:09:29.091: I/MediaPlayer(3152): MediaPlayer 

04-23 16:09:29.091: I/MediaPlayer(3152): MediaPlayer setDataSource(context, uri,headers)

04-23 16:09:29.201: I/MediaPlayer(3152): MediaPlayer setDisplay()

04-23 16:09:29.311: I/MediaPlayer(3152): MediaPlayer handleMessage what=5

04-23 16:09:29.311: I/MediaPlayer(3152): MediaPlayer handleMessage what=1

04-23 16:09:29.311: D/MediaPlayer(3152): getMetadata is coming on console while coming back to privous activity so it is taking long time to back to previous activity

Comment: Having the same issue: if an Activity has a VideoView, and the user has played something there once, and then onPause / onResume happens (e.g another Activity was launched above, or Home button pressed) -> then this onResume hangs up for a while, plus after that AlertDialogs don't work any more. Must be some Android bug or something..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you intialize this in oncreate of activity-

```
final VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
            myVideoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/demovideo.mp4");
            MediaController controller=new MediaController(this);
            myVideoView.setMediaController(controller);
            myVideoView.requestFocus();
```